# Django - Custom model field with default value

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I set default value for timestp field ?

Default value > 'NOW()'

```
class Timestamp(models.Field):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'timestamp'


class MyModel(Model):
    # ...
    my_field = Timestamp()
```

Comment: check this one https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a class for this. Django has `auto_now_add` attribute.

```
class MyModel(Model):
    # ...
    my_field = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    #To save without timezone override the save method
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_field = self.my_field.replace(tzinfo=None)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I want datetime without zone. DateTimeField create field with timestampz.

Comment: its not a good idea in large applications with fifty models.